# Hibernate Envers wrong modified flag on list

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-envers

I use Envers to audit my data and sometimes the value of the `_MOD` is incorrect. It stays at `0` instead of `1` when I am adding an element in my list. But it happens only in a specific case.

My entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSONNE")
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
public class PersonEntity {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "ID_PERSONNE")
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "NAME", length = 100)
   private String name;

   @Audited( withModifiedFlag = true, modifiedColumnName = "SERVICES_MOD")
   private Set<PersonneServiceEntity> services = new HashSet<>(); // Entity with attributs, gettters, setters and envers annotations...

   @Audited( withModifiedFlag = true, modifiedColumnName = "OPT_INS_MOD")
   private Set<OptinEntity> optIns = new HashSet<>();// Entity with attributs, gettters, setters and envers annotations...

  
   // more fields
   // + getters, setteurs, equals, tostring
```

my service:

```
// personFromDB is retrieve via an Id 
private void update(PersonEntity personFromRequest, PersonEntity personFromDB) {

    personFromDB.setName(personFromRequest.getName());
    updateServices(personFromRequest, personFromDB); // add new support to the list
    updateOptins(personFromRequest, personFromDB); // add new services to the list

    personDao.saveAndFlush(personFromDB);
}
```

This is were the magic happens: When I am updating `name`, `services` and `optIns`. Values in my database are all correct, my entity is correctly persisted, **except one envers's column**: `OPT_INS_MOD` ( `OPT_INS_MOD == 0`).
But if I am not updating the name ( line commented ) then everything is correctly persisted including all `_MOD` values ( `OPT_INS_MOD == 1` and `SERVICES_MOD` ).
And finally if I am switching `updateSupport(personFromRequest, personFromDB)` and `updateServices(personFromRequest, personFromDB)`, in this case `OPT_INS_MOD` is correct but not `SERVICES_MOD`.

My guess is that there is a problem when Envers is getting all modified fields. Because it does not make any sense to me.

Any ideas? I am using Envers version **4.3.11.Final**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will help you because it doesn't sound like the same problem but I've noticed a weirdness with modified flags and collections.

I get my entities back from the front end converted from JSON back to POJOs. In order to keep from having a transient object error from Hibernate, I need to reset the value in the @Id field (which was never sent to the FE). This works fine for 1-1 entities.

On collections, I found that if I create a new instance of the collection class and fill it with refreshed entities from the old collection and then assign that new collection to the old attribute, the modified flag is set to true.

However, if I fill a new collection with refreshed entities, clear() the old collection, then add all the items in the new collection, modified flag will be false unless there were actual changes to the collection.